# Remove path to uninstalled codeblocks

Tags: 14.04, apt, uninstall

I uninstall `codeblocks` via these commands (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove codeblocks
sudo apt-get --purge remove codeblocks
```

After that I run:

```
$ codeblocks
bash: /usr/bin/codeblocks: No such file or directory
```

That means `codeblocks` is still stored in a PATH somewhere.

So I have a few Qs:

- Is the way I used the correct way to safely uninstall everything of `codeblocks`?
- If so, why the path is still there (isn't it part of the uninstalling process to remove the path as well)?
- Where is the file that I can manually remove that obsolete path?

Thanks.

Comment: Does `hash -d codeblocks` get rid of it? if so, it was just stored in the shell's program cache (see `help hash`); if not, we will need to probe further ...

Comment: spot on, it helped remove the path, and now when I trigger codeblocks from command line, 14.04 would ask for a new install - that's what I need. I suggest you convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the name is still stored in the bash shell's program name cache: if so, you can remove it by typing

```
hash -d codeblocks
```

or (to clear the entire cache)

```
hash -r
```

Since `hash` is a shell built-in function, it is documented under the bash manual page (`man bash`) or via the online help function `help hash`.