# /usr/local/bin/bower: No such file or directory after reinstalling Node.js and bower

Tags: apt, package-management, nodejs, npm

I reinstalled `nodejs` (`node`,`npm`) because of an old corrupted configuration. Than I installed `bower`

```
$sudo npm install -g bower
/usr/bin/bower -> /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
/usr/lib
└── bower@1.8.0
$which bower
/usr/bin/bower
$bower -v
bash: /usr/local/bin/bower: No such file or directory
```

I do not know where\how I should clean the broken link.

Comment: Are you sure it's an alias? what does `type bower` say?

Comment: bower hashed (/usr/local/bin/bower)

Comment: In that case it should be sufficient to do `hash -d bower` - see this related question [Remove path to uninstalled codeblocks](http://askubuntu.com/questions/654885/remove-path-to-uninstalled-codeblocks/654891#654891)

Comment: @steeldriver, please put your comment to answers, I'll mark it like correct answer - it helps me.

Answer (score 2):

`hash -d bower` and you'd be good to go.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me !