# How to link command to correct program?

Tags: bash, symbolic-link, paths

I've installed a command called `gsutil` on my Ubuntu VM with the command

```
sudo snap install google-cloud-sdk --classic
```

However, when running `gsutil` I started an unrelated existing program of the same name (`GSutil, a GrandStream BudgeTone phone backup, restore and reboot utility`), which was stored in `usr/bin/gsutil`. Following advice from [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-dev/nq88A6v-Bt0/q0lNNalySH8J) I ran

```
sudo dpkg --purge gsutil
```

which removed it. But now when I run `gsutil` I get

```
-bash: /usr/bin/gsutil: No such file or directory
```

With `which gsutil` I get

```
/snap/bin/gsutil
```

And I tried to make a symlink with

```
ln -s /snap/bin/gsutil gsutil
```

but still get the same results. Why can't bash find it? Both locations are in my PATH:   `echo $PATH`

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: Are you still in the same shell? if so, see similar [Remove path to uninstalled codeblocks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654885/remove-path-to-uninstalled-codeblocks)

Comment: Yes, it must have been cache! Logging in afresh solved it, otherwise I'm sure that would have worked. Thank you - happy you to mark as solved if you want to make it an answer.